# How does paging work on the C# Facebook sdk

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Cannot find any documentation for this...

Currently using the following code to get a list of my photos:

```
FacebookApp fb = new FacebookApp(accessToken);
dynamic test = fb.Get("me/photos");
```

I'm cycling through the first 25 photos that it returns. Simple.

Now how do it get it to return the next 25?

So far I've tried this:

```
FacebookApp fb = new FacebookApp(accessToken);
string query = "me/photos";

while (true)
{
    dynamic test = fb.Get(query);

    foreach (dynamic each in test.data)
    {
        // do something here
    }

    query = test.paging.next;
}
```

but it fails throwing:

```
Could not parse '2010-08-30T17%3A58%3A56%2B0000' into a date or time.
```

Do I have to use a fresh `dynamic` variable for every request, or am I going about this the wrong way completely?

Comment: This question has much better information : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41418671/how-is-facebook-graph-api-pagination-works-and-how-to-iterate-facebook-user-feed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ended up finding this:

```
// first set (1-25)
var parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.limit = 25;
parameters.offset = 0;

app.Api("me/friends", parameters);

// next set (26-50)
var parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.limit = 25;
parameters.offset = 25;

app.Api("me/friends", parameters);
```

Comment: You should use "dynamic parameters = "

Comment: Is there a way to play with cursor based pagination for feed? with facebook C# SDK?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41418671/how-is-facebook-graph-api-pagination-works-and-how-to-iterate-facebook-user-feed

Comment: Sorry but this is very bad practice for several reasons

Answer (score 5):

I also found you can use this.

```
// for the first 25 albums (in this case) 1-25
dynamic albums = client.Get("me/albums", new { limit = "25", offset = "0"});

// for the next 25 albums, 26-50
dynamic albums = client.Get("me/albums", new { limit = "25", offset = "25"});
```

Worked the same as you used above.

Comment: I like using dynamic wherever possible solely because is scares my colleges so much.

Comment: This could potentially give you duplicates if a new album was added. The whole point of the paging system is to discourage this.

Comment: See Coding Freak's answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41418671/how-is-facebook-graph-api-pagination-works-and-how-to-iterate-facebook-user-feed