# Facebook Graph API: Inferior permissions

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I had a great idea for an application, so I started checking out what the graph API had to offer. Then I've found out that it doesn't have access to large swathes of information that I can freely access on the website. I've got all the access token stuff working fine, it just appears that the Graph API doesn't have access to a lot.

On the website, there are more than 100 photos of me tagged in the last year. With the Graph API I can only get around 20. Most photos posted by my friends are missing.

So if I still really want to do this, what are my options? Guessing scraping is against the TOS?

**UPDATE**

[This link](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=72605) appears to have a response to a user with the same issue. Apparently its a privacy issue...

Comment: can you post an example of the code you're using?

Comment: Reading the original question I'm unsure if you only want all the photos of yourself, or if that's just an example and you're really looking for a broader solution to perceived limitations in Graph API?

Comment: Its nothing to do with the code I'm using. Even if I manually read through json results there are only about 20 photos for "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=..." within the last year. This is a limitation of all requests. If I look up my friend "https://graph.facebook.com/123456789/albums?access_token=..." whose photos I can freely view on the website, the response via the graph API is simply { "data": [ ] }

Comment: @John Yes, I'm just looking for a solution really. I really want to make this app, but I feel like I've fallen at the first stumbling block!

Comment: @Jim: I feel your pain in facebook development in general.

Comment: I forgot to ask what programming language you're using?

Answer (score 0):

There's an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664197/how-does-paging-work-on-the-c-facebook-sdk/4675359#4675359) (about paging limits and offsets) that might be useful if your problem is related to default paging sizes in the Graph API.

Comment: That's my answer to my own question! It does appear to be a limitation of the API. I think the the Android Facebook application uses the Graph API as its missing the same albums...

Comment: Can you set limit to a huge number and offset=0 to get them all at once, or do you have to keep getting 20 at a time?  In the latter case you still have access to them all although, admittedly, it's a bit of a pain that way. So you can access them all eventually?

Comment: Nope. However you query the API, you don't have the same permissions as when you are logged in to the website, so many photos, posts, etc are missing. I don't have any issues (now) cycling through and getting photos, its just the API doesn't have access to everything. If a user has set an album so it is only visible to friends, this is not visible to the API, even if you are using an access token that should be able to view the album...